# Sine value using recursive function in C

Tags: c

I am getting negative and positive result : when I enter(n value odd) odd term produces even or and even term produces odd value. I have already made function for factorial it works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.14159f

int factorial(int n);
float sine(float , int);
int i;

void main(){
    float degree;
    float radian;
    float result;
    int n;
    printf("Enter the angle in degree: ");
    scanf("%f",&degree);
    printf("Enter the iteration: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    radian = degree * PI / 180;
    result = sine(radian,n);
    printf("%d",factorial(n));
    printf("\n");
    printf("sin%.2f = %.3f",degree,result);
}

int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n==0)
        return 1;
    else if (n==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (n*factorial(n-1));
}

float sine(float an, int n)
{
    if (an==0)
        return 0;
    else if(n>=0)
        if(n%2==1)
            return (sine(an,n-2) - pow(an,n)/factorial(n)) * pow(-1,n);
        else
            return (sine(an,2*n-1) - pow(an,2*n+1)/factorial(2*n+1)) *-1 ;
}
```

Comment: You need to decide whether `n` follows a sequence like `7,6,5,4,3,2,1` or `n` follows a sequence like `7,5,3,1`. You seem to have a mixture of both.

Comment: and you need to decide whether n<=0 case.

Comment: @user3386109 can you send code please?

Comment: @JunheeShin please send code

Comment: @JunheeShin code is working for even value of n Its not working for odd number
please read question properly

Comment: code is working, but not giving correct outputs for any input except for 0

Comment: @Subham Try in code block its working for even number

Comment: @willsir I already included all necessary headers and added all prototypes, why do you need `math.h`? still it wont give a correct output

Comment: @willsir you are right we need math.h for `pow()`, I forgot about it since I was running your code as C++

Comment: @Subham please don't put code longer than one line in comments, as you see it is unreadable. [Edit] your question instead.

Comment: @MichaelWalz i have edited question can you tell me how to fix please the error?

Comment: @willsir please format your C code correctly. Like the samples in your C text book.

Comment: @Michael Walz sir... this isnt my question

Comment: @Subham not your question but my hint. Take it or leave it.

Comment: @MichaelWalz you are mistaken, its not me who put the lengthy code in the comments, it was willsir

Comment: @Subham oh, sorry. My mistake.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I have already deleted lengthy code from comment please help to fix my problem

Comment: @Subham Thank you for your help sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float sine(float an, int n)
{
    if (an == 0)
        return 0;
```

The above condition returns 0 for sin(0) so it is of no use in rest of the recursion and it works fine.

```
else if(n >= 0)
    if(n%2 == 1)
        return (sine(an,n-2) - pow(an,n)/factorial(n)) * pow(-1,n);
    else
        return (sine(an,2*n-1) - pow(an,2*n+1)/factorial(2*n+1)) *-1 ;
```

Lets see where this part of your function goes, by substituting the value of n:
Suppose we are start with degree = 30 and number of iterations = 3
Then:

```
n = 3;
```

n is odd so function returns:

```
((sine(an, 3-2) - (float)pow(an, 3) / factorial(3)) * -1);
n = 1;
```

n is again odd so function returns:

```
((sine(an, 1-2) - (float)pow(an, 1) / factorial(1)) * -1);
n = -1;
```

This time `n < 0` so if-else conditions are skipped and **some garbage value is returned** because you did not tell your program what to return at `n = 0`
So you need your sine-function to return a default value when `n = 0`

`pow(-1,n)` will always return -1 for odd values of n, and 1 for even values of n. So the sign of output of sine() function is not changing alternately like in the series.

**Answering to the comment: Why the sign seems to change for odd or even,**
In your code values of n are skipping the even numbers, instead of decreasing n by 1 per call, you are passing only odd numbers.
`return (sine(an,n-2) - pow(an,n)/factorial(n)) * pow(-1,n);`
so what you get in the end is a sum of negatives; And when you start with a even value of n like 2, then sine() is called with odd value of n the second time which is (2*n-1) which again returns a sum of negatives.

**Heres what you can do:**

```
float sine(float an, int n)
{
    if (an == 0 || n == 0)
        return 0;   //to end the recursion when number of iterations are finished
    else
        return -1*pow(-1,n)*pow(an,2*n-1)/factorial(2*n-1) + sine(an, n - 1);
}
//  `-1*pow(-1,n)` returns a negative term for even value of n, and postive term for odd value of n as required. You dont need separate if-else for that
```

Comment: @willsir if the problem has been solved, can you share the new code by pasting here >> [http://pasted.co](http://pasted.co)

Comment: if sign is not changing then why sin90 = 1.00 (n=5,9,13) and sin90 = -1.00(7,11,15) i.e. for odd term of odd number result is positive and for even term result is negative

Comment: remove that tick from my answer till the problem is not completely solved, otherwise experts in the topic may ignore your question, thinking its solved

Comment: check my answer again, i have answered your comment there

Comment: thanks and why if(n==0)
       return 0;
please explain that too

Comment: Every time sine() function calls itself, (n-1) is passed to it. So value of n keeps decreasing. We want to stop at n=0 thats when all iterations are finished. In declaration of sine(), we declared its return type is float. So if we dont return anything, some garbage float value is returned which gets added to the previous level, thats why we are returning 0, since adding 0 will not change value of the output.